# Combinatorics - Number of streaks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have $n$ bins, and $t \in \{0,1,\cdots,n\}$ balls. How many ways are there to arrange the balls, such that we have exactly $j$ streaks of 3.

Examples: $n=5$, $t=4$

OOO_O - includes 1 run of 3.

_OOOO - includes 2 runs of 3.

Comment: So, you're allowed to put at most one ball in each bin?

Comment: This can be done with the Goulden-Jackson cluster method; see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.5113.

Comment: Are you still here, knrumsey?

Comment: Sorry guys. Yes, at most one ball in each bin. Apologies, I should have been more clear. @Tad, thanks I'll check it out.